# Ignore locale prefix for specific route in nuxt-i18n module

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

For all pages, I need the locale prefix. But for the profile page, I want to ignore it.

```
All pages except profile
/{en|da|sv}/path

Profile page
/peter.hansen
```

I select prefix strategies at nuxt-i18n configuration option. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: You may look into https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/routing#ignore-routes.

Comment: I tried it. But locale prefixes can not be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a late answer but incase someone come looking at this.
Just follow : https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/ignoring-localized-routes by adding either to the page file:

```
//pages/about.vue
export default {
  nuxtI18n: false
}
```

or globally:

```
//nuxt.config.js
i18n: {
  parsePages: false,
  pages: {
    about: false
  }
}
```